# Streaming a video on iPhone and then storing it on the device

Tags: iphone, video, ipad, streaming, video-streaming

I've been told that some apps have video streaming which streams initially and when completely downloaded the video is stored to the user's device for quick and internet-free subsequent viewing.

Firstly, is this possible? Secondly, could you point me towards resources demonstrating how it could be done, or possibly offer some insight to get me started?

Thanks friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

good tutorial on how to stream video:

http://buildmobilesoftware.com/2010/08/09/how-to-stream-videos-on-the-iphone-or-ipad/

Comment: Thanks Sheehan, but this answer doesn't really address the issue of storing the video on the device, which is sort of central to the question.